# Rule based grouping of data into segments LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, grouping

I need to group data into segments based on some preset rules. I have input data taken in 5 minute intervals and sometimes more than 5 minutes.
I need to put them into segments for further processing, but it does not work for me for some reason.

Example of data:

```
11.01.2017 14:59:19 +01:00   value 15
11.01.2017 15:04:19 +01:00   value 17
11.01.2017 15:09:19 +01:00   value 14
11.01.2017 15:14:19 +01:00   value 11
11.01.2017 15:19:19 +01:00   value 0
11.01.2017 15:24:19 +01:00   value 8
---------here I want divide---------
11.01.2017 15:49:19 +01:00   value 6
11.01.2017 15:54:19 +01:00   value 14
11.01.2017 15:59:19 +01:00   value 5
11.01.2017 16:04:19 +01:00   value 3
11.01.2017 16:09:19 +01:00   value 5
```

Here is the example code: http://rextester.com/GQW59118

There should be two segments in the example.

I need something like this

```
var grouped = dataList.GroupBy(tv => /*group when is dataList[i]-dataList[i-1]==5 */)
                .Select(g => g.OrderBy(tv => tv.dateTime).ToList()
                ).ToList();
```

Can anyone please advise?
(without if in loop)

Comment: Please post your code in the question even if you have a link to it.

Comment: why do want to use linq for arrays? linq is good for xml or db. use simple loops and addition structures.

Comment: @AlexeyObukhov LINQ to Objects is often easier to maintain, because it's more readable. Besides, you can use LINQ for many data sources, even web-based, not just XML or DB.

Comment: but not more debuggable

Comment: Why only two?  You would have 14:45 to 14:50, 14:50 to 14:55, 14:55 to 15:00, 15:00 to 15:05, 15:05 to 15:10, ..........

Comment: @jdweng You are right that there couId be more segments, but I need to divide the data when the interval is larger than 5 min. which only accounts for two in this case.

Comment: Try this : var grouped = ttcaList.GroupBy(tv => (int)((tv.Time - tv.Time.Date).TotalMinutes - 49 )/60)
                .Select(g =>
                  g.OrderBy(tv => tv.Time).ToList()
                ).ToList();

Comment: @jdweng This only works for data from single day, but I need it to work for data from i.e. 19 days period.

Comment: Basically I need to take data from some randomly long period and make a selection according to preset rules. Through this, I need to get list of segments containing data in 5-minute intervals, which I will than use for further analysis.

Comment: My code will work for long periods if you change tv.Time.Date to something like DateTime.Parse("1/11/17") which will give you midnight on first day.  Then break up segments in 1 hour increments.  The '-49' is required if you start a test in the middle of the hour.

Comment: @jdweng I do not exactly understand your code. I try your modification but It not works.
http://rextester.com/YJEH75463

Comment: You want to divide code in one hour segments.  So if the test started on at 11:00AM you want all the date until Noon to be in one group which is 60 minutes.  So using midnight as reference 11:00AM is 660 minutes and Noon is 720 minutues.  So dividing by 60 gives a number between 11 <= x < 12 being in one group.  The subtraction of 49 is an offset so all data between 11:49 and 12:49 are in one group.  So try this : var grouped = ttcaList.GroupBy(tv => (int)((tv.Time - DateTime.Parse("1/1/2017")).TotalMinutes - 49 )/60).Select(g => g.OrderBy(tv => tv.Time).ToList() ).ToList();

Comment: @jdweng The segments can have random length. (from 15 minutes to 2 hours).

Comment: How can you tell where the segment split if it is random?

Comment: @jdweng I wanted to avoid the loops (with if cond.), but now I see that there is apparently no other (faster) way to do it.

Comment: It is a two step process.  One is to define the segments.  Second is to put data into segments.  Sometimes a problem like this can be done in one loop, and others require two loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
         List<TimeValue> ttcaList = new List<TimeValue>();

        Random s = new Random();
        DateTimeOffset dto = DateTimeOffset.Now;  


        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        {
            ttcaList.Add(new TimeValue(dto.AddMinutes(i*5), s.Next(0, 20)));
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            ttcaList.Add(new TimeValue(dto.AddMinutes(10*5).AddMinutes(i*5), s.Next(0, 20)));
        }


        foreach (var item in ttcaList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Time+"   value "+ item.Value);
        }

        List<List<TimeValue>> grouped = new List<List<TimeValue>>();

        var interval = 5;
        DateTimeOffset lastTime = new DateTimeOffset();

        foreach (var item in ttcaList)
        {

            if (grouped.Count == 0) 
            {
                grouped.Add(new List<TimeValue>() {item});
                lastTime = item.Time;
            }
            else 
            {
                if ((item.Time - lastTime).TotalMinutes <= interval)
                    grouped.Last().Add(item);
                else 
                    grouped.Add(new List<TimeValue>() {item});

                lastTime = item.Time;
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("\n\n grouped data");

        foreach (var skup in grouped)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\t\t group");
        foreach (var item in skup)
        {

            Console.WriteLine(item.Time+"   value "+ item.Value);
         }
        }
    }
```

There you have time interval 5 minutes, you may change it by changing the value of `interval`

Comment: I have it like this. I want it resolve by LINQ, but maybe it is not possible.